# Every time i face an error whenever i try to track my user in google map

Tags: kotlin

[Here are some bugs I don't know why its occurs In fact my code is work in the tutorial which I follow I mentioned my bugs inside stars below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BRYq.png)

```
private fun startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.*requestLocationUpdates*(
        locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        null
    )
}

private fun getLocationUpdates() {
    locationRequest = *LocationRequest()*
    locationRequest.*interval* = 30000
    locationRequest.*fastestInterval* = 20000
    locationRequest.*priority* = LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback(){
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()){
                val location = locationResult.lastLocation
                if (location != null){
                    val latLng = LatLng(location.longitude, location.longitude)
                    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)))
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f))
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: locationRequest.interval
 locationRequest.fastestInterval
 locationRequest.priority

For those values, verify the actual variable, because those properties are not present on the metod / variable / function being called, so double check them.
Take a look at this example

val name = "Antonio"
    println(name.toUpperCase())
.toUpperCase() is a built in function of the strings

Comment: I check them but not work

Comment: I try to use the same thing for solve my issue. But again it indicates me the bug in place of this "requestLocationUpdates" and show me that create an extension function for this